# Synonymize [spa] with [single-page-application]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

[spa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spa) questions are all about [single-page-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application). The tag has currently 64 questions with the following excerpt:

> SPA is a short of Single Page Application.

I would have suggested a tag synonym if I had the necessary score.

Comment: I'd be on the fence if this actually needs to be merged or not. SPA is the more common way to refer to this type of application design and quite unique to it too as far as I know, so why would you need a lengthy tag such as 'single-page-application' to spell it out? If you what to know specifically about SPA's, you know what the abbreviation means.