# Synonymise [singlepage] with [single-page-application]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both tags, [singlepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlepage) and [single-page-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application), are about SPA (single page applications), both wiki tags make reference to the same docs:

- [Single Page Interface in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)
- [Single Page Interface Manifesto](http://itsnat.sourceforge.net/php/spim/spi_manifesto_en.php)

Related

- [Synonymize [spa] with [single-page-application]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277697/1595451)
- [A list of tag synonyms which are not proposed in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342097/1595451)

Comment: Full support, these are essentially one tag. There is also a [tag:spa-template] that may be worth synonymizing for visibility (or dealing with altogether with 18 questions attow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag synonym was already proposed by John Papa on Nov 16 '12, and had gathered 2 votes! I added the final vote and approved the synonym, that is:

[singlepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlepage) (× 219) → [single-page-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application) (× 4378)

As usual, I'll wait for a few days before merging the two tags, in case there are any issues with the synonym.